# Avoid 'Remote request only' error Message when Node Server access domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, remote-access

Using `Node.js`, I am trying to send a `GET` request to server and I've used the following code for that.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://example-domain-name/', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data);
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

The problem is that, the server is responding statusCode 500 (*Runtime error*).

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

But browser is displaying the page normally, but using node js request, i get the something following response data(text).

How to avoid this and normally request and response data like browser using `node.js`?

Please Help... [StackOverFlow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) is only my basis of help now!!

Comment: I believe it's not your problem. http status error 500 was returned from the remote host. It's very likely the remote server has runtime error or it has connection check if the connection comes from a browser(i.e. user-agent, header/cookie check, etc.) and block any connections which are not coming from browsers.

Comment: When browser access the site, that site is working normally!

Comment: How to use node.js to access that site just like browsers?